# Create a transpose table from data frame

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I Have a big data base of below sample data . I am trying to create a function which can filter Dept from Dept column one by one and the from filtered subset data create a table for all filtered managers like below.

Managers can be many or less for dept , so that it can create table dynamically for filtered managers. because sometimes managers can be 1-23 or more for dept.

I tried with the help filtering and transposing data and then binding it but that is not working properly for me as i am medium proficient in dplyr only.

```
df <- data.frame(Dept = c("CA","HR","CA","HR","HR","CA","HR","HR","CA","CA","HR","CA","CA"),
                 Manager = c("AKASH","MANU","AMAN","SANU","NISH","KAMAL","VEER","SANIL","SAMEER","KANU","NUKUL","KUNAL","RAMIT"),
                 PF = c("Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No"),
                 Yearlybonus=c(6946,5871,0,7173,2161,3008,0,3025,4323,4196,0,5594,2313),
                 Quaterlybonus=c(2683,3846,0,2391,6716,6012,5479,3869,3764,0,4632,0,2371),
                 monthlybonus=c(4453,6466,2811,6845,4377,2617,0,7631,7761,2944,6270,3534,5856))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `data.table` for large dataset

This solution does not accumulate transformed data as list. Instead, it uses a function for filtering data

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df)
df[, `:=`(Yearlybonus = as.character(Yearlybonus),
         Quaterlybonus = as.character(Quaterlybonus), 
         monthlybonus = as.character(monthlybonus))]
```

This function is a pure function, because it sends a copy of data (df) to function everytime. If you have less memory space, you could refactor this function to use the data (df) from global scope. The refactored code will look like the ones in commented lines.

```
# myfun <- function(x) {
myfun <- function(df, x) {
  # wide to long
  # y <- melt( df[Dept == x], 
  df <- melt( df[Dept == x], 
             id.vars = c('Manager'), 
             measure.vars = c('PF', 'Yearlybonus', 'Quaterlybonus', 'monthlybonus'), 
             variable.name = 'T' )
  # long to wide
  # y <- dcast(y, T ~ Manager, value.var = 'value')
  df <- dcast(df, T ~ Manager, value.var = 'value')

  # add dept column
  #y[, Dept := x ]
  df[, Dept := x ]

  # set column order in memory
  #nm <- names(y)
  nm <- names(df)
  nm <- c('Dept', nm[nm != 'Dept'])
  #setcolorder(y, nm)
  setcolorder(df, nm)

  #return(y[])
  return(df[])    }
}

# create index for speed
setkey(df, Dept)

# myfun(x = 'CA')   
myfun(df = df, x = 'CA')

#  Dept             T AKASH AMAN KAMAL KANU KUNAL RAMIT SAMEER
#1:   CA            PF   Yes  Yes    No  Yes   Yes    No     No
#2:   CA   Yearlybonus  6946    0  3008 4196  5594  2313   4323
#3:   CA Quaterlybonus  2683    0  6012    0     0  2371   3764
#4:   CA  monthlybonus  4453 2811  2617 2944  3534  5856   7761

# myfun(x = 'HR')   
myfun(df = df, x = 'HR')
#   Dept             T MANU NISH NUKUL SANIL SANU VEER
#1:   HR            PF   No  Yes   Yes   Yes  Yes   No
#2:   HR   Yearlybonus 5871 2161     0  3025 7173    0
#3:   HR Quaterlybonus 3846 6716  4632  3869 2391 5479
#4:   HR  monthlybonus 6466 4377  6270  7631 6845    0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(unique(df$Dept), ~df %>% filter(Dept == .x) %>% 
  mutate(across(Yearlybonus:monthlybonus, ~as.character(.x))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(PF:monthlybonus, names_to="T", values_to="vals") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="Manager", values_from="vals"))


# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 9
#   Dept  T             AKASH AMAN  KAMAL SAMEER KANU  KUNAL RAMIT
#   <chr> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 CA    PF            Yes   Yes   No    No     Yes   Yes   No   
# 2 CA    Yearlybonus   6946  0     3008  4323   4196  5594  2313 
# 3 CA    Quaterlybonus 2683  0     6012  3764   0     0     2371 
# 4 CA    monthlybonus  4453  2811  2617  7761   2944  3534  5856 
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 8
#   Dept  T             MANU  SANU  NISH  VEER  SANIL NUKUL
#   <chr> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 HR    PF            No    Yes   Yes   No    Yes   Yes  
# 2 HR    Yearlybonus   5871  7173  2161  0     3025  0    
# 3 HR    Quaterlybonus 3846  2391  6716  5479  3869  4632 
# 4 HR    monthlybonus  6466  6845  4377  0     7631  6270
```